# Excel VBA: Maintaining number formatting with digits and letters

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code where basically I need to follow the sequence in logic. I am going through all the lines

```
Set rep = Sheets("Details")    
For i = 2 To n    
If Sheets("Work").Range("A:A").Find(Worksheets("Work_report").Range("E" & i).Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then    
Else:    
o = rep.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1    
rep.Range("A" & o).Value = "FT_EXCEL"    
rep.Range("B" & o).Value = Sheets("Start").Range("C5") & "AB" & o - 1    
End If    
Next i
```

So this the last line (there are more than 50 in original code) returns me a value of the cell C5 (20170331) & AB & the o minus 1 (because I have started at 2 (1st line header)). So this is giving 20170331AB1, but it should give 20170331AB01 (zero before the 0). This sequence works like a charm after 10, but before ten when I need to add a zero - I got stuck.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rep.Range("B" & o).Value = Sheets("Start").Range("C5") & "AB" & Format(o - 1, "00")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim Williams. Exactly what I needed, simple and efficient, kudos!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in one shot with exploiting `AutoFilter()` method's `operator` `xlFilterValues` value

```
Sub main()
    Dim rep As Worksheet

    Dim criteriaArr As Variant
    With Worksheets("Work_report") '<--| reference "Work_report" sheet
        criteriaArr = Application.Transpose(.Range("E2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Value) '<--| store its column E cells content from row 2 down to last not empty one
    End With

    Set rep = Sheets("Details")
    With Worksheets("Work") '<--| reference "Work" sheet
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=criteriaArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter it with "Work_report" sheet column E content
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cells other then headers
                With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference filtered cells skipping header
                    rep.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = "FT_EXCEL" '<--| write 'rep' sheet column A corresponding cells content
                    With rep.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count)
                        .Formula = "=CONCATENATE(Start!$C$5,""AB"",TEXT(ROW(),""00""))" '<--| '<--| write 'rep' sheet column B corresponding cells content
                        .Value = .Value
                    End With
                End With
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```